# iscsi_trgt missing because can't build kernel module

Tags: modules, iscsi

When attempting to start the iscsitarget service, I get

> FATAL: Module iscsi_trgt not found.

Trying to build module using instructions from http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/iscsitarget/index.php?title=Unofficial_DEBs fails and the build log only has a single line in it saying the build started. Nothing about the failure.

Comment: Which ubuntu-version do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your ubuntu-version.

On newer systems (since Maverick) you have to install some additional packets:

```
sudo aptitude install iscsitarget iscsitarget-source iscsitarget-dkms
```

This compiles the required module automagically.

On Lucid you have to compile yourself (and maybe again after every kernel-update):

```
sudo aptitude install iscsitarget iscsitarget-source
# compile with module-assitant
sudo m-a a-i iscsitarget
```

Comment: These are the instructions I had followed. The question is how to determine why the compile is failing.

Comment: The log-files can be found under /var/cache/modass. Have you tried the -t -v options (text-mode + verbose)?

Comment: In ubuntu 11.10 oneiric ocelot, installing above mentioned packages  will automatically compile the required kernel modules and install it to the system.

After that, you can run;
`sudo /etc/init.d/iscsitarget start` to start the iscsitarget service. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Sajith, This may be true in general, however the same package broke for me when upgrading from 10.04. I had to apt-get install iscsitarget-dkms to fix it then add the module manually. Not sure why. The above directions did fix it though. :)

Answer (score 2):

If none of the solutions are working, try following:

```
apt-get install --reinstall iscsitarget-dkms
```

This re-installs the `iscsitarget dkms` and resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all of the above and couldn't fix the error, but finally got it working with:

```
apt purge iscsitarget
apt install iscsitarget
```

If nothing else is working then give this a shot.